# AndroidManifest "android.hardware.fingerprint" not working

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-fingerprint-api, uses-feature

My app should only be installed on devices that have a fingerprint sensor. (Marshmallow+). In AndroidManifest I have the following code:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint" android:required="true" />
```

However, some devices on Google Play are marked as "incompatible", but do work when the APK is installed manually. Why does this not work as it should?

Comment: The devices marked as incompatible are shown to you on the Google Play Developer Console or is it shown to the customer in the Play Store?

Comment: @Robert On the Console and for the user.

Comment: It does seem to work [as it should](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html): _"Google Play filters the applications **that are visible to users**, so that users can **see and download** only those applications that are compatible with their devices. 
... [T]he Android system itself **does not check for matching feature support on the device before installing** an application."_

Comment: @Michael I know, but why does Google Play remove devices that have a compatible fingerprint sensor?

Comment: Ah, that I don't know. I read your question as _"Why can people install my app on devices that lack a feature I require?"_

Comment: @SuperThomasLab: Have you checked that the device reports it's features correctly?

Comment: @Robert I think that part goes wrong. I don't have such device to test. Do you know of a workaround? (Maybe add those devices manually, just a few devices).

Comment: @SuperThomasLab: When I execute `adb shell pm list features` on a Nexus5x I can see the `feature:android.hardware.fingerprint` entry. If you know someone with a device that makes problems may be the owner can send you the feature list. Or you add a possibility to your app to display the list of supported features.

Comment: @Robert thanks. Do you know if it's possible to include a device manually on Google Play, if it's not compatible?